# Disable black lines after you hover on a point of 3d scatterplot

Tags: r, plotly

Is there a way to disable the black lines from the point after you hover on it?

```
plot_ly(mpg, x = ~cty, y = ~hwy, z = ~cyl) %>%
+     add_markers(color = ~cyl)
```